# Angular ng-disable button when it's content has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a tic tac toe game where I play against an AI. I am able to disable the buttons when I click on them but not when the AI changes the content of it's button (the AI is technically not clicking on the button). I am wondering how to go about this in Angular. I can do it in jquery/javascript but can't figure it out in Angular. http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/meNeoJ?editors=101

```
<body ng-app="ticTacToe" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="container choose">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>CHOOSE A SHAPE</h1>
      <button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-red" id="choose-cross">✖</button>
      <button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-green" id="choose-circle">◯</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper" class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <button ng-click="move(cell);isDisabled=true" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-repeat="cell in cells" class="col-xs-4 square text-center">
        {{cell.value}}
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
  $scope.AI = "";
  var cross = "✖";
  var circle = "◯";

  /*** Choose a shape ***/
  $scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
        $('.choose').css('top', '-2000px');
        $('#wrapper').css('top', '-600px');
        $('#wrapper').css('opacity', '1');

    if($scope.player === cross){
    $scope.AI = circle;
    }else if($scope.player === circle){
    $scope.AI = cross;
  }
}

  /*** Shape Cells ***/
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];
  // made a ref to scope cells
  $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells;
  $scope.filledCells = $scope.cells;

  //disable cells with "✖" or "◯" <---- Can't figure this out
    for(cell in $scope.filledCells){
      if(cell.value === '✖' || cell.value === '◯'){
        cell.isDisabled = true;
      }
    }

  //$scope.disable();
  /*** Make a move ***/
  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
    var round = 0;
    /*** AI makes a move ***/
    while(round < 1){
     // filtered to get only available cells (for performance)
      $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells.filter(function(cell){
        return cell.value === '';
      });
      // got random cell according to empty cells
      var randomCell =  $scope.emptyCells[Math.floor((Math.random()*($scope.emptyCells.length-1))+1)];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
      randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
      round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      } 
    }
  $scope.checkResults();
  };
var winningNums = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
   ];


  //checks if values are the same
  $scope.checkResults = function(){
    var allCells = $scope.cells;
    for(var i = 0; i < winningNums.length; i++){
        var a = winningNums[i][0],b=winningNums[i][1],c=winningNums[i][2];
        var cell1 = allCells[a].value, cell2 = allCells[b].value, cell3 = allCells[c].value;
      if(cell1 == "" || cell2 == "" || cell3 == "" ){
        break;
      }
        if(cell1 === cell2 && cell2 === cell3 ){
            var winnerDiv = "<div><h1>" + cell1 + " is the winner</h1></div>";
          $(
"#wrapper").append(winnerDiv);
        }

      }

  }

$scope.reset = function(){
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a jsbin and I hope, it is what you want. Unfortuanately, codepen is taking too much time to load

https://jsbin.com/xawode/edit?output

I bind the disabled property with cell disabled property. So when a user selects a cell or AI, cell disabled property is going to be set `true`

```
var randomCell =  $scope.emptyCells[Math.floor((Math.random()*($scope.emptyCells.length-1))+1)];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
      randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
        randomCell.disabled = true;
      round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      }
```

JS Bin on jsbin.com

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed. I did something similiar before but I didn't add a `disabled` property to the `cell` object.

Comment: Happy to know that.. choose your best answer before throwing this question into dustbin

Answer (score 0):

Use the isDisabled as property of cell object

```
<button ng-click="move(cell);cell.isDisabled=true" 
        ng-disabled="cell.isDisabled" ng-repeat="cell in cells" 
        class="col-xs-4 square text-center">
        {{cell.value}}
</button>
```

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle, so exact console error can be seen